# what is the best solution for automated testing of react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, automated-tests

We(my project) have a big site, which I would like to test, **automatically**. We already have about 2k of unit test that are written using Jest + Enzyme. So as our project continue growing, I wanted to ask about "how to automatically test the site?". I had an expirience using Selenium + Java + Cucumber, also some cypress + cucumber, but sometimes I don't want to go through the multiple pages thousand times just to test some small feature. Is there way to test separately some page? E.g. I display JUST specific page as I was loggined, and I want to test automatically just that form.

I had the idea that I could create special routes for testing, and just open them on a virtual machine on the running local server.

I don't want tests to go through the full flow e.g. go on registration page=> fill "About you form" => go on next step =>fill "Company details" => go on next step => Fill "Marketing recommendation". E.g. I want to test just Marketing recommendation page, so I don't need to fill about you information and company details information in each test, because It would take additional time and probably would fail due random backend issue or so on. I would like to click on some selectors on the Marketing page and I expect to see some Error message(or not)

Answer (score 1):

very opinion based question but I recently found out about Storybook and I would like to try it out at some stage.

https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/get-started/introduction